# Create Zoom Meeting that anyone can join

Tags: python, zoom-sdk, zoom-meeting

I am trying to create a Zoom Meeting that will allow any user to enter without host permission. Currently, I am able to create a meeting successfully, however, no one can join the meeting unless the host starts it or let anyone in.

This is my payload:

```
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'
}

payload = {
    "topic": "Your Meeting Topic",
    "type": 3,
    "join_before_host": True,
    "waiting_room": False,
    "settings": {
        "approval_type": 2  # Automatically approve participants to join
    },
    "recurrence": {
        "type": 2,  # Type 2 for weekly recurring meetings
        "repeat_interval": 1,  # Repeat every week
        "weekly_days": "1,2,3,4,5"  # Monday to Friday
    }
}

response = requests.post(create_meeting_url, json=payload, headers=headers)
```

I think I am using the correct payload to create the kind of meeting I required but still not able to do it. I did go over the documentation too: https://developers.zoom.us/docs/meeting-sdk/apis/#operation/meetingCreate. Can someone please guide me that what I might be doing wrong here?

Also, I noted that for some reason this issue is only on this Zoom Account (Pro). I also tried it with my free account and it worked fine on that. The meeting link on Pro account does not have any `pwd param` in the url. However, the meeting link that I get from Zoom Free Account contains `pwd param` in the url.

Answer (score 0):

To allow participants to join without host permission, you should set the "join_before_host" option to True, which you have already done. However, it seems that you are also setting the "approval_type" to 2, which might be causing the issue.

For meetings where participants can join without host permission, you should set the "approval_type" to 0.

Comment: I did try `approval type` with `0` too but I still need to wait in the waiting room until host admit me. Not sure what am I doing wrong here. @annman